# Function and Files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm using Python 3.6. I wrote a simple function:

```
def data(filename, file):
    data(filename=input(), file=open(filename))
    return file.read()

print(data)
```

and got an error like this:

> "C:\Users\Jack The Reaper\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:/Users/Jack The
>   Reaper/Documents/untitled/untitled.py"
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

I don't have any idea what is going on, please explain.

Comment: `data` is a function so to call it you need `()`, it also has 2 parameters which you need to pass so something like `data('myfile.txt', x)` although I wouldn't have a parameter `file`

Comment: What are you trying to do? This function is recursive and never called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an error.
You declared a function.
In Python, function are objects, so when you printed the function you printed the function object, which is printed as `<function data at ...>`.

To call the function, use `()` e.g. `print(data("file.txt", open("file1.txt")))`.

However your function calls itself unconditionally, which will cause a stack overflow (infinite recursive calls).

I suppose you meant something along this:

```
def data(filename):
    file = open(filename)
    return file.read()

print(data("myfile.txt"))
```

or, to handle the file properly,

```
def data(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        return file.read()

print(data("myfile.txt"))
```

You can also, of course, get the filename in the function:

```
def data():
    filename = input()
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        return file.read()

print(data())
```

Answer (score 3):

Pythonic answer:

```
def data():
    try:
        with open(input("Filename?\n"), "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            return f.readlines()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found, please enter correct filename")
        data()

print("".join(data()))
```

I realise that you are probably new to python so I will try to explain a bit.

`def data():` opens a block to define a function named data, that takes no argument. All the code following this statement that is indented once (usually with 4 spaces or 1 tabulation) will be the core of our function named `data`. `data` is its reference, but to call it you need to add `()` like this: `data()`, otherwise you're just saying "this function" instead of "run this function" to the interpreter.

The `try: ... except: ...` blocks are very common and should be used over `if`s in python. Here we are "trying" to open a file specified by the user by a prompt and return its content in a list. If this operation fails with a `FileNotFoundError`, it means the user probably entered an invalid filename, and instead of exiting on that error, we run the code inside the `except` block. There, we print a sentence to tell the user that his filename was wrong, and we make a call to the function itself (recursion) to start the process anew, giving the user another chance at entering a correct filename. The function will thus not exit until a correct filename is given.

`input("Filename?\n")` is the part that displays "Filename?" on the screen, and waits for the user to enter something, and then returns whatever was entered as a string.

`open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8")` opens the file `filename` for **reading** (specified by the `"r"`), and tries to interpret the bytes from the files as a utf-8 encoded piece of text (if you do not specify `encoding="utf-8"` it will work only if your file contains simple ascii characters).

The `with ... as ...:` block is called a context manager. When you open a file, it is good practice to close it. We could just call `close(the_file)` when we are done with it, but if the program crashes in between, the file was not closed. The context manager ensures that *however* we exit the `with` block, certain actions will be executed. In cases of files, it ensures they are properly closed.

The `readlines()` method is a file method that outputs the content of your file in a python list, with each element of the list being a line of your file. It is convenient when you want to iterate over all the lines in your file.

Comment: If you're just printing the result, it's not of much use, but usually you're going to want to process the file data, and it is usually more convenient to have lines in a list, but it's just my advice and depends on what you will do with the data. Using `read` is all good too.

Comment: That's right, but 1. it complicates the answer 2. isn't always true (e.g. with json file)

Comment: Python is not about what is *always* true, but what *seems most likely* ;) it looked like the most likely way to me to output the file content, because I usually have more use from `readlines` but as I said this is subjective, and depends on the OP's needs.

Comment: I totally agree.